# Early uses of the word "operator" in mathematics

Tags: mathematics, terminology

I'm looking for early uses of the word "operator" in mathematics and how it evolved to become a synonym for the modern "function" in certain areas. Jeff Miller's [page](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/o/) only has an entry for "operation" and "operand".

Comment: "Linear operator" seems to have become widespread in 1891-1893, according to Google Books; O. Heaviside was a big user & maybe popularizer of the term.

Answer (score 3):

The unabridged Oxford Dictionary is of great help in such matters. It requires subscription. Here are the examples it provides since 1855.

> Originally: (Mathematics) a symbol or group of symbols indicating an
> operation or series of operations to be carried out, usually on a
> following expression. Later also: a sign or symbol which effects other
> types of operation, as logical, phonological, syntactic, etc.
>
> 1855  R. Carmichael Treat. Calculus of Operations 3   The
> indetermination is due to a source quite independent of the character
> of the functional operator.
>
> 1925   J. M. Bryant & J. A. Correll Alternating-current Circuits iii.
> 74   The operator, j = √(− 1), turns the vector through 90 degrees in
> a counterclockwise direction each time it is used.
>
> 1952  Eng. & Germanic Stud. 4 12   We may regard Modern English stone
> as the result of operating with an operator that I shall write {AS. ā
> MnE. [ou]} on Anglo-Saxon stān.
>
> 1969   V. J. Calderbank Course on Programming in FORTRAN IV iii. 28
> The relational expression..has the general form e1re2 where e1 and e2
> are arithmetic expressions..being compared by one of the following
> relational operators, r: .EQ. Equal to (=); .LT. Less than (<);
> [etc.].
>
> 1990   Proc. London Math. Soc. 60 365   The centroid operator and the
> projection operator are quite different. For example, the centroid
> operator commutes with linear transformations, while the projection
> operator does not.